# Eclipse/STS - through command line - what is the parameter to refer an epf file at Eclipse startup?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Having either STS or Eclipse

I am able to startup Eclipse, through command line, for a specific workspace through:

- `<Eclipse location>/Eclipse -data <path to some workspace>`
- `<STS location>/SpringToolSuite4 -data <path to some workspace>`

Until here all work fine.

Because I have multiple workspaces and a `master.epf` file for them, I want refer it each time I start Eclipse. Therefore I want avoid do manually use `File -> Import -> Preferences` and wait a restart

Therefore something like:

- `<STS location>/Eclipse -data <path to some workspace> -??? <path to the epf file>`

Therefore if is possible, what should be the `???` value?

I read:

- [The Eclipse runtime options](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

And not sure what could be.

In that link `data` has the following description:

```
-data <location> (OSGi)
    equivalent to setting osgi.instance.area to <location>
```

At a first glance, seems unrelated that `data` is used to define a custom workspace at Eclipse startup

I am assuming there is a parameter to accomplish my request

Comment: I would recommend to raise a bug at Eclipse for this. I don't think there is a way to do this at the moment, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Done, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563641 I hope it goes well